# JQuery callback outside the function with parameters for dynamically changing page content.(and how to make it simpler)

Tags: jquery

I am new here so sorry if I did something wrong

So I have been trying to make a course website menu. There is a lesson list and when clicked it will change the lesson div content. It loads the related lessons instead of reloading the page or changing the url. I did this so that I don't have to write every lesson page and add header or footer. Much easier.

So I have been searching internet for days but couldn't find something that fits with what I want. So I wrote this. And I want to share it with everyone who wants something like this. I like jQuery so I don't use Js a lot.

**What I want to ask is :**

*Can I make it simpler and is there another way?

Is this gonna be heavy or cause any problems with browsers?(I tested but it looks ok for now)*

```
/* Function for loading courses to div */
$(document).ready(function () {

 /* Make the function global for callback outside of the function */
window.buttonLoadCourse = function (id, link) {

 /* Function itself */
$(id).click(function () { 
$(".course-content").load(link);
        });
    }
});
/* Outside callback for loading the courses */
buttonLoadCourse((".lesson149"), ("lesson149.html") )
buttonLoadCourse((".lesson150"), ("lesson150.html") )
buttonLoadCourse((".lesson151"), ("lesson151.html") )
```

**For example:**

- Lesson 3
- (when clicked it will open: "Lesson 3 content in allocated      div")
- Lesson 3: Basics of Italian Cuisine etc.

Thank you so much

Comment: If this is working code that you want reviewed then this would likely be a better fit here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't see a reason that the method has to be put on the window, when the method calls could be made inside the document ready.

Comment: Thank you David. I will have a look.I want to use it in a different js file and also for styling and proper coding

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a better solution:

```
$('.loadLessonButton').on('click', function (clickEvent) {
  // get the page link from the clicked button
  var clickedButton = clickEvent.currentTarget;
  var link = clickedButton.getAttribute('data-page');
  $('.course-content').load(link);
})
```

Then we need to change the HTML for this:

```
<button class="loadLessonButton" data-page="lesson149.html">Lesson 149</button>
<button class="loadLessonButton" data-page="lesson150.html">Lesson 150</button>
```

- No need for window. as we can call our functions inside the element
- Some improvements on parameter naming
- Added variables for ease of reading and use
- Hope this helps some people